# executing history command as another user

Tags: bash, command-history

I am confused as to why I'm having problems executing a history command as another user to return all that user's history - I need to loop though all users and get their history

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}' > ${system}.users.txt
while read username; do
   echo $username
      sudo -u $username bash -c 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "; history' >../log/${username}.hist
      #sudo -u $username bash -c 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "; history'
done < ./${system}.users.txt
```

I get no history output when I run:
`sudo -u anotheruser history`

to troubleshoot I tried:
`sudo -u anotheruser bash -c 'which history'`

Also I ran :
`sudo find / -name 'history' -type f`

and I get no returned executable.

Can anybody tell me why a sudo command can't be executed by another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `history` is a shell builtin; there is no executable

(2) `bash -c` makes `bash` noninteractive, and noninteractive shells don't use history. This is not very well documented, but I need both `-i` and `set -o history` to get history into a shell with `-c`:

```
bash -ic 'set -o history; history'
```

(Tested in 4.1.2(1) on RedHat and 4.3.11(1) on Ubuntu)

(3) timestamps aren't written to the history file by default, so unless you've (previously) set/forced `HISTTIMEFORMAT` for your users or they have (previously) deliberately set it, lines/entries read from the history file will (all) have the current time

(4) `sudo` changes the userid and groupid but not the rest of the environment, so your command will look for the history file of the user running it, not the one in `$username`; add `-i`

(5) It might be easier to just read `$5/.bash_history` -- at least for userids that run bash and have a home directory, which system userids mostly won't

Comment: A second user was not getting it's history timestamped until I executed 'set -o history'. I noticed that the data is encoded above the command within my the .bash_history file without issuing 'set -o history', so for my user in ubuntu 14.04 it seems to be setup with timestamped history automatically (but like you say I need HISTTIMEFORMAT to show the timestamp).  Differences between distros perhaps?

Comment: @rupert160 HISTIMEFORMAT is required to either display timestamps or _write_ them to the file. `set -o history` is at least for me required to get the noninteractive shell to _read_ the file; without that it doesn't have any past history to display with or without timestamps.